# How to continue on failure in test step using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How do I continue on failure in test step using robot framework? `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` jumps on another test case. I do not want to jump to next test case, I want to continue executing all steps in my test case.

Comment: According to the documentation, `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` is expected to continue executing the same test case:  http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Run Keyword And Ignore Error    name , *args
```

Runs the given keyword with the given arguments and ignores possible error.
This keyword returns two values, so that the first is either string PASS or FAIL, depending on the status of the executed keyword. The second value is either the return value of the keyword or the received error message.

Comment: is any other way, i will just declare test case level or test suite level and it continues all the steps ignoring errors. Why i am asking this feature is , it will be helpful, it will continue all the step validations and if it fails in other steps that also comes in the report , which is more useful. If execution stops after find error, it will give only that error, after that execution will be success or not, we cannot assure.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally in end to end testing, if any of test step fails then the whole test case should fail. So we have to design automation test cases keeping this in mind. This is the first point.

Secondly, if you have to do something, (like reset a setting, or logout kind of thing) irrespective of your test step execution result, you can use test case level keyword teardown. This the best approach to deal with issue you have.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: yes, one way you are correct @hemant, but we can test other steps and consolidately can give all the errors and ultimately test case will be failed, if we can run the test case ignoring errors